# How to make a C# source file to be processed by the Visual Studio, but NOT compiled in the assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I have many C# script source files in the project tree marked as `Build Action: None`

**The problem is**: if the source file is marked as `Build Action: None` then `Go To Declaration`, `Go To Implementation` and other navigation and refactoring functions of Visual Studio and Resharper doesn't work anymore.

The script files are eventually compiled by the `CSharpCodeProvider` once the app is running and generally behave 100% the same as if they were in the actual code base (the original executable assembly).

The difference here is that the source files are not compiled by MSBuild, but by the app itself.

**How can I force Visual Studio/build process to analyze the files (as if they were going to be compiled) without including them into final executable assembly?**

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the main project file (`.csproj`) and add an `AfterBuild` target, you can invoke any custom action on post build. The following example calls compile.exe for all `Build Action=None` items in the project with extension of `.proj`.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">

  <ItemGroup>
    <Scripts Include="@(None)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.proj'" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="Scripts files: @(Scripts)" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="Compile.exe %22%(Scripts.FullPath)%22" 
        WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
        Condition="'@(Scripts)' != ''"  />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to have different build configurations, with different settings for the files in question.

You can have a development configuration, where the files are set to 'compile', and a deployment configuration, where they're set to 'none'.

That way, you'll get nice Intellisense when working on your code, and no compilation happening when you flip to 'deployment' configuration before you build.

Comment: You can't change build configurations while the app is running. Also that is a good idea only IF there is a hotkey for switching build configurations. The key idea with these scripts is rapid iteration - they are automatically rebuilt and incorporated in the running app when an event is fired by the FileSystemWatcher. All the additional activities should be eliminated.

Comment: You're using VS 2010, so you can create as many of your own macros and hotkeys as you like! :)